# Texture Baking help

Tags: texturing, texture-baking

Hello to whomever is reading. I have a model that i am trying to bake my textures to, they are non-pbr textures. I am trying to tell blender to bake using those textures but I do not know how to do that. I want to bake them a certain way for easy use of reskinning the model. If anyone can help I would be greatly appreciative. I have tried using texture painting but blender crashes due to the boolean cuts on certain parts.

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "*this*", "*help with*", "*issue*" or "*question about*", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: Here is a tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qd3lUFUpiIw
I use this addon, it's a lifesaver.